# Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and factor vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to combine a list of table into a data frame, drop a column and convert it into a "wide" table of counts by sample.
I have loaded

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

also, count.tables is a list of length 22

When running

```
count.df.long <- bind_rows(count.tables, .id="Sample")
```

It gives me the warning:

> Unequal factor levels: coercing to characterbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vectorbinding character and
>   factor vector, coercing into character vector

And on the next step

```
count.df.wide <- count.df.long %>% select(-"percent") %>%
spread(Sample, count)
```

I get:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2572, 7337, 12726, 17661,
>   21013, 27067, 32036, 38334, 43223, 49353, 55049, 58820, 63874, 68410,
>   73324, 76677, 81930), (24259, 46481), (1638, 6608, 11922, 16110,
>   20102, 26133, 30977, 37723, 42343, 48437, 54291, 58335, 62672, 67791,
>   71971, 75944, 81169), (719, 5894, 11230, 15400, 19522, 25214, 30352,
>   36596, 41348, 46807, 47557, 53380, 57427, 62124, 66883, 71266, 75198,
>   80171), (1792, 7089, 12285, 16581, 20543, 26287, 31527, 37878, 42488,
>   48596, 54313, 58508, 63003, 68108, 72622, 76042, 81280), (4907,
>   29402), (18736, 39958, 60499), (2957, 7438, 14843, 17092, 21436,
>   27452, 32434, 39173, 43452, 49540, 56178, 59821, 64385, 69488, 82672),
>   (1401, 6379, 11808, 15987, 20141, 25896, 31207, 37357, 42117, 48419,
>   54132, 58199, 63159, 67944, 71942, 76002, 81011), (2600, 7622, 12579,
>   16842, 21292, 27095, 32362, 38749, 43279, 49226, 55018, 59297, 63735,
>   68704, 73255, 77283, 82003), (1486, 6576, 11731, 15896, 20012, 25981,
>   31001, 37319, 41990, 48375, 53953, 58211,

I wonder what is the first error, how to fix it, and if the second error is related to that first one?

Thanks!

Elena

Comment: Create a sequence column after select i.e. `count.df.long %>% select(-percent) %>% group_by(Sample) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%> spread(Sample, count)`

Comment: Note that the reproducible example should be *minimal*: you don't use packages `DESeq2` and `ggplot2` so there is no need to load them.

Comment: @akrun Do you mean something like this `count.df.long <- bind_rows(count.tables, .id="Sample")

count.df.long %>% select(-percent) %>% group_by(Sample) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%> spread(Sample, count)` 
It shows the same error and then `>count.df.long %>% select(-percent) %>% group_by(Sample) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%> spread(Sample, count)
Error: unexpected '>' in "count.df.long %>% select(-percent) %>% group_by(Sample) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%>"`

Comment: For spread(x, y) you should have at most n_distinct(x) times n_distinct(y) rows, since you're using those values to fill table with those dimensions. Anyway, if you need a more specific answer, I agree that a reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original files were named under the same filename sampleX (from a previous mistake) so the count.df.long was creating a table with the "control" and "sampleX" as the only two Sample ids, therefore, detecting an infinite number of duplicate variables within "sampleX" which was meant to be Sample1, 2, 3... The names have been re-names with the corresponding file name and the error has been fixed.

The first warning keeps coming up (still not understanding why) but the final output is the desired and expected so I am happy.

Thanks for your replies.